# How can I delete a database row in this example?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a problem when the user has clicked on the "Cancel" button. When the user clicks on the "Cancel" button, I want it to delete a row in the database by navigating to the cancelimage.php page. But it is not deleting the database row of the file which has been uploaded but then canceled. By looking at the code below, why is it not deleting the row from the database and how can it be coded so that it does?

Below is the startImageUpload() function where it starts uploading and where the cancel button function is featured:

```
    function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

    ...

                $(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {

var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');

                jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php"  + image_file_name)
                    .done(function(data) {

                    $(".imagemsg" + _cancelimagecounter).html(data);
                });

                return stopImageUpload();

            });       
                  return true;
            }
```

Below is the cancelimage,php page where it is suppose to delete a row from the database?

```
<?php

$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="xxx";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$image_file_name = $_GET["fileImage"]["name"];

    echo "File Upload was Canceled";

        $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
        WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/". mysql_real_escape_string($image_file_name)."'";

    mysql_query($imagecancelsql);

    mysql_close();


?>
```

Below is the php script (imageupload.php) where it inserts a database row:

```
<?php

session_start();


$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="xxx";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$result = 0;

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;

        $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
        VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";

mysql_query($imagesql);

      mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I'm pretty sure there would be nothing in the $_FILES variable on the call to cancelimage.php

What you could do is pass the name of the image as a parameter to the cancelimage.php script and the use that in your query.

Comment: i have updated my code, I am not sure if I have passed the name of the image but can you see if I am doing this because with the updated code I still can't get the database to delete the row.